# Task :expo-crypto:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED after installing expo-auth-session

Tags: react-native, expo

After installing `expo-auth-session` the android build is crashing.

```
> Task :expo-crypto:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was resolved after adding `expo-crypto` and all the other dependencies mentioned in `yarn.lock`.

I think the error occurred because `expo-crypto` is the dependency of `expo-auth-session`.

screenshot from yarn.lock.
[image]